# Renaming wordpress login and get new password button

Tags: filters, hooks

I am currently building custom wordpress admin login theme.Now I have an idea but not sure it is possible.I want to rename "Get New Password" to something "Get New".
Is it also possible to rename "Log In "  to "Go"?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you hoping to modify the default login page? Or create a new page entirely?

Comment: I am trying to modify default login page.I know by jquery it is possible and I can do that.I am hoping to do that by using filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad idea for general usage plugin, unless you intend to supply translations for all the languages for which there is a wordpress translation.

If you need a new login form then use new strings for the text, don't override the string used in the wordpress login form, it give you no advantage to do that. This way the lack of translation will be expected not come as a surprise.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Kaplun.I am a bit crazy.You know rules are made to be broken.....